# Proving proposition 4.1 in undergraduate analysis

Tags: real-analysis

## Theorem

Let $D$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z^+}$. Then $D$ is denumerable,
and in fact there is a unique enumeration of $D$, namely ${ k_1 , k_2 ,....}$
such that

$$k_1 < k_2 < ... < k_n < k_{n+1} < ....$$

## Proof.

We let $k_1$ be the smallest element of $D$. Suppose inductively that we have defined $k_l < k_2 < ... < k_n $ in such a way that any element $k$ in
$D$ which is not equal to $k_1, ... ,k$ is $> k_n$. We define $k_{n+ 1}$ to be the smallest element of $D$ which is $> k_n$. Then the map $n\rightarrow k_n$ is the desired enumeration of $D$.

## Confusion

The proof states that $k_{n+1}$ is the smallest element in $D$ (....We define $k_{n+ 1}$ to be the smallest element of $D$...). Then it declares $k_{n+1}>k_n$ (...smallest element of $D$ which is $> k_n$.). Isn't this contradictory?

Comment: "The proof states that $k_{n+1}$ is the smallest element in $D$" No, it does not, actually it states "We define $k_{n+ 1}$ to be the smallest element of $D$ **which is $> k_n$**".

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting that sentence. It's not taking $k_{n+1}$ to be the smallest element and then claiming that that element is greater than $k_n$. Rather it is taking the smallest element in $D \setminus \{k_1, \dots, k_n \}$ (that is the smallest element in $D$ amongst those that are greater than $k_n$)

Comment: Oh so it basically says that create a subset from $D$ which doesn't have $k_1 ......k_n$ and then extract the smallest element from it. Call it $k_{n+1}$ and then include that in your excluded set. Right?

Comment: yes, that's right.